# AlexNet model provided with Caffe

Tags: python, model, deep-learning, caffe, imagenet

I have been using TensorFlow but I am new to Caffe. I wanted to try out a reliable implementation of AlexNet trained on ImageNet and I found one included in the [official Caffe repository](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_alexnet).

I was able to link the weights packaged in [**bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel**](http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel) file and the model specified in [**deploy.prototxt**](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt) in a very short Caffe code and obtain an output vector of 1000 probabilities corresponding to the 1000 categories the network classifies the images into.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import caffe
import operator

MODEL_FILE = 'D:\\Desktop\\caffe\\models\\bvlc_alexnet\\deploy.prototxt'
PRETRAINED = 'D:\\AlexNet_Caffe\\bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel'

net = caffe.Classifier(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED)


IMAGE_FILE = 'D:\\Desktop\\caffe\\python\\testIm1.jpg'
input_image1 = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)

IMAGE_FILE = 'D:\\Desktop\\caffe\\python\\testIm2.jpg'
input_image2 = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)


pred = net.predict([input_image1, input_image2])
print pred # prints the array of 1000 probabilities


index, value = max(enumerate(pred[0]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

print index # prints the index of max probability
print value # prints the max probability


index, value = max(enumerate(pred[1]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

print index # prints the index of max probability
print value # prints the max probability
```

**In my case, I am able to just specify the model and weights and obtain an output, however, the output seems to be the same (669) regardless of whatever image I input.**

In the Caffe repository, there is a [script for fetching ImageNet dataset](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh). The tarball it downloads and extracts contains the following files:

```sh
$ ls -al
total 80395
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 197121        0 Aug  8 14:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 197121        0 Aug  7 16:27 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121      187 Feb 25  2014 ._imagenet_mean.binaryproto
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121      187 Apr  8  2014 ._synset_words.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121      187 Feb 25  2014 ._synsets.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121      187 Feb 25  2014 ._test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121      187 Feb 25  2014 ._train.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121      187 Feb 25  2014 ._val.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121 17858008 Aug  8 14:09 caffe_ilsvrc12.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121     3787 Jun  8  2014 det_synset_words.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 197121      610 Aug  8 13:41 get_ilsvrc_aux.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121 14931117 Jul 11  2014 imagenet.bet.pickle
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121   786446 Feb 25  2014 imagenet_mean.binaryproto
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121    31675 Apr  8  2014 synset_words.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121    10000 Feb 25  2014 synsets.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121  3200000 Feb 25  2014 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121 43829433 Feb 25  2014 train.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 197121  1644500 Feb 25  2014 val.txt
```

I am not sure if I also need to use the files `imagenet_mean.binaryproto`
and `imagenet.bet.pickle`

Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subtract image mean.

When deep models are trained the inputs are usually normalized to have roughly mean=0. In case of Caffe's AlexNet, the image mean is saved in `imagenet_mean.binaryproto`.

See [this example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb) on how to use a pre-trained model to get classification results.